# Is it possible to have custom keywords in trac syntax highlighting?

Tags: c, customization, syntax-highlighting, trac

As we all know, Trac has the ability to use [WikiProcessors](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/WikiProcessors) to apply some syntax highlighting on code used in tickets etc.

Now, I have this C application that is full of custom types, macros etc. In Vim, I could simply create a syntax file, store it under `syntax/after/c/myproject.vim` and – tadaaaah – my editor knows my keywords.

Is there such a possiblity for the Trac syntax highlighting (i.e. can I define custom keywords somehow)?

Comment: Since Trac [utilizes Pygments](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSyntaxColoring), it might be possible to use [Pygments filters](http://pygments.org/docs/filters/) to add the feature to Trac without too much effort.

Comment: @RjOllos: okay. How would I do it? Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: I'll try to take a look and work up an example, but it might be a few days before I get to it.

Comment: The code for the default C lexer is here (https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/pygments-main/src/33931e753e368c0393631356d9d652d4b3019ffe/pygments/lexers/compiled.py?at=default), you may be able to use that as a starting point.

Comment: Looking at this again, I think you may need a custom [lexer, filter or formatter](http://pygments.org/docs/). A slightly different feature is proposed in [#11862](http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/11862). I'll continue thinking about your feature request while implementing that change.